# Selectors are executed before component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

my selectors are executing before the component in which they are mapped are rendered. Why would this be? For example in the code below, the `messages` selector is executed before the `Component` renders. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as selectors from './selectors';

const Component = ({message}) => (
  <div>
    {message}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  message: selectors.message(state, props),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

Comment: because otherwise redux would be unable to provide appropriate props into component. why do you expect it should go in different ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React-Redux v5, the internal selector that implements `mapState` is [initialized in the wrapper component constructor](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L136), and [is called right away as part of that process](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L195).

In React-Redux v6, that internal selector is [created in the wrapper component constructor](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v6.0.0/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L177), but [called during the render process](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v6.0.0/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L200-L204).

Comment: Thanks mark! I'm having some trouble though setting up redux v6 though, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732984/upgrading-to-redux-v6). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So curious Mark. Everywhere I look people say selectors are awesome. But no one mentions that they are eager. Am I doing something wrong? Because as you see, I add these selectors to my mapStateToProps, but their eagerness means they first evaluate an incomplete state.

Comment: What do you mean by "incomplete state"?

Comment: Well, I don't want my selectors to be executed until I have fetched some data, which then further populates my redux state / stores. But often my selectors happen before those fetches are complete.

Comment: Then you'd need to add conditional logic in your `mapState` function to handle the cases where that data may not yet exist.  The contract of `mapState` is that it will be executed _every_ time the root store state has changed.  If your component will be used in cases where the data it needs might not yet be in the store, you need to account for that somehow.

Comment: Ok, so what about the mapState of a component that has not been rendered yet? It will be executed every time the root store state has changed as well? And thus, as you said, this now changes with Redux v6 such that mapState will only be executed when the component it is connected to renders?

Comment: Once a component has mounted, `mapState` will run every time the store state changes.  The only slight difference in behavior here between v5 and v6 is the exact timing of the first call to `mapState`.  What specific concerns do you have related to this?

Comment: I've upgraded up redux v6 and yet my selectors are still executing before their appropriate components are mounted. I must be doing something wrong. I'm going to try and create a codesandbox of this issue to try and debug / replicate and will let you know. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: My guess is that you're misinterpreting how the React and React-Redux lifecycle is supposed to behave.  Remember that a React component will render once _before_ `componentDidMount` executes.  But yes, please create a CodeSandbox that reproduces your concerns, and go ahead and file an issue on the React-Redux repo.