# Upgrading to Redux v6

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to upgrade to Redux V6 but am confused on how to use the createContext function and it's necessity. I know my store is created successfully, but when I try to run my app I get

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConfiguredApp)".
>   Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React
>   context provider to  and the corresponding React context
>   consumer to Connect(ConfiguredApp) in connect options.

Which tells me that my provider is not properly passing down the store for `connect` to grab. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'connected-react-router';
import {history, store} from './store/store';
import Routes from './routes';

const customContext = React.createContext(null);

render(
  <Provider store={store} context={customContext}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} context={customContext}>
      <Routes />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost definitely shouldn't be creating and passing in a custom context instance.  That's *only* if, for some very specific reason, you want to use a context instance other than the default one that React-Redux already uses internally.  (A hypothetical reason to do this would be if you are using one store for your whole app component tree, but there's a specific subtree that needs to receive data from a different store instead.)

*If* you actually wanted to use your own custom context instance, then you would need to pass the *same* context instance to *both* `<Provider>` and each connected component in the app that needs to receive data from that `<Provider>`.

Looking at the `connected-react-router` docs, they do claim that in CRR version 6, you can pass a context instance to `<ConnectedRouter>`, but that shouldn't be necessary here.

More specifically, if you look at the error message, it says the problem is in `Connect(ConfiguredApp)`.  So, it's your own connected component that is saying there's a context mismatch.

Ultimately, the answer here is to delete the `context` arguments from both `<Provider>` and `<ConnectedRouter>`.  You don't need them.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! Problem is, my connected component doesn't seem to be listening to state changes now. This isn't a feature of Redux v6 is it? It should behave just like before, right?

Comment: Yes, it should behave the same otherwise.  Hard to say what else is going on without seeing the rest of your app, though.  If you can put up a CodeSandbox project that reproduces the issue, I can maybe take a quick look.

Comment: It turns out the issue was I forgot to upgrade to react-dom to 16.4 as well.

Comment: Yep, _always_ keep your React and ReactDOM versions exactly the same.